# Circle is clipped for no obvious reason

Tags: pstricks

I guess, this might be a fairly simple one as I am a TeX newbie...
I already searched on Google but did not find an answer to my question (maybe because I did not really know what to search for exactly.)

I want do draw a circle of fifth and when making the pspicture environment as big as the circle is, the letters around the circle are clipped, as they exceed the canvas.
When enlarging the canvas though, the letters are printed just fine, but the circle isn't anymore. When also displaying gridlines, I see that even the gridlines are not shown on the far-right...
Does anyone know, why? Or even more important for me: how to avoid that? :-)

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}
\newcommand{\textsharp}{$\sharp$}
\psset{unit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](-12,-12)(12,12)

\pscircle[linewidth=2pt]{10}
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{10 t PtoC}{w}

\uput[!N-w0.y N-w0.x atan](w0){$A$}
\uput[!N-w0.y N-w0.x atan 180 sub](w0){$f^\sharp$}

\uput[!N-w1.y N-w1.x atan](w1){$D$}
\uput[!N-w1.y N-w1.x atan 180 sub](w1){$h$}
% ...skipping some lines...

\uput[!N-w11.y N-w11.x atan](w11){$E$}
\uput[!N-w11.y N-w11.x atan 180 sub](w11){$c^\sharp$}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm working with TeXworks on a Microsoft Windows environment.

Here's the result with bigger canvas:

```
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](-12,-12)(12,12)
```

[image: circle is cut, but all letters are visible]

The circle is cut.

When I resize the canvas to exactly fit the size of the circle, it is fully drawn, but the letters are outside the canvas:

```
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](-10,-10)(10,10)
```

[image: circle is fully visible, but letters are outside the canvas]

Strange, isn't it...
I don't have a clue.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Looks fine over here (compiled using xelatex from texlive-2015 and looked at with Preview.app on Mac OSX 10.9).    Have you tried using a different PDF viewer?

Comment: Yes, I've used two different PDF viewers. Both show the same result.

Comment: Good point. Now looks also fine here, after manually compiling the source code using `latex filename.tex` followed by `dvips filename.dvi`. The postscript output looks good, but the PDF that is automatically created by texworks does not. Any clue, why?

Answer (score 1):

You need at least

```
\fontsize{48pt}{48pt}\selectfont
\newcommand{\textsharp}{$\sharp$}
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors,showgrid](-10,-10)(11,10)
```

to show the letter A on the right side because `standalone` will clip everything around the coordinates. 
And, of course, you missed the `\selectfont`

Comment: That does not help. When i use (-10,-10)(10,10), the letter A is not shown. That's clear and I fully understand that. But what I do NOT understand is, that the output is clipped when I specify (-12,-12)(12,12).

Comment: I also have no problem with `(-12,-12)(12,12)`. Please run the example with `xelatex`. Is it the same problem?

Comment: Yes, the same problem. I also used xelatex before.

Comment: looks like a problem with the `xetex.def`  driver. Which version do you have

Comment: 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)